# Can we change the value of attribute on after/before Create() callback in sails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a scenario where I have to populate attribute of model with its id. For eg..
In User model:

```
module.exports = {
attributes: {
    activation_link: "string"
},
 afterCreate: function(value, cb) {
    value.activation_link = "localhost:1337/user/action/"+ value.id;
    cb();
}
```

The activation_link's modified value has to saved in the database too. How can that be achieved?

Comment: You don't really state what the issue is that you're having, but I'm going to assume that you're expecting your changes to be persisted to the database *again* after the `afterCreate` call.  This is not the case.  The object that is returned to the callback of `User.create()` will be modified (i.e. it will have an `activation_link`), but the database record will not.

Comment: @sgress454 exactly, I need the modified value to be saved in the database. How can that be achieved?

Comment: For anyone else that is interested, I believe that this does what @LujaShrestha was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26618046/2110294

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/9d5a46fa49cd1f39e1d911bd5bfd547aafc1cea5/test/unit/callbacks/afterCreate.create.js#L18) and [this](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/9d5a46fa49cd1f39e1d911bd5bfd547aafc1cea5/test/unit/callbacks/afterCreate.create.js#L48) your code should actually work: your manipulations in `afterCreate` are supposed to mutate the resulting object.

**UPDATE**

Hmm... Seems like the first parameter is not a Waterline object, despite of [what the documentation says](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/50affb138011440d2a3c74a2390aed54ae846fd6/README.md). Technically, you can refetch the record from DB by id, update and save without a lot of overhead (since it's supposed to be only called once upon creation). But I would really avoid putting in the DB a field that depends on a record id: such DB becomes untransportable, since you can't guarantee that the records will have the same ids. So, the solution would be either use some tokens for these activation links (the clean way) or just make `activation_link` a function without putting it in the DB (the simple way):

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
  },
  activation_link: function() {
    if (!this.id)
      return false;

    return 'localhost:1337/user/action/' + this.id;
  }
}
```

Comment: console.log() after the manipulation shows the required value but its not being saved in the database. Any additional steps required?

Comment: I would suggest you can try `value.save()`, since you are in `afterCreate`, it shouldn't cause any loops.

Comment: @Lujaw Check the updated answer, if something like this can work for you.

Comment: not exactly, the solution I was looking for, it is a viable solution. Thanks for the ans @bredikhin

Comment: I think the documentation / code is being read wrong and the updated answer is inaccurate. Although it would be nice for a waterline object to be returned. It is not really referenced in any of the docs or code you list above. It simply says the values are passed.

Comment: @Meeker https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/50affb138011440d2a3c74a2390aed54ae846fd6/README.md#lifecycle-callbacks, `fn(newlyInsertedRecord, cb)` kinda looks like a promise of a Waterline object (comparing to `fn(values, cb)`).

Comment: @bredikhin "kinda looks like" is not really the claim you make in the answer. It is really subjective. To me it is showing you that your getting the values as they were inserted in to the DB and not those necessarily passed to create function. Although I feel like it should return a Waterline object, the docs/code you make reference to do not validate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change from `afterCreate` to `beforeCreate` (sails -v 0.12.14)

```
beforeCreate: function (attrs, cb) {
    attrs.createdAt = moment().format()
    attrs.updatedAt = attrs.createdAt
    return cb();
  },

beforeUpdate: function (attrs, cb) {
    attrs.updatedAt = moment().format()
    return cb();
  }
```

document here [offical sails model lifecycle](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks)