# Sailsjs/waterline specify number of decimal places in model

Tags: sails.js, waterline

How do I tell my sails model that I want some specific number decimal places for a `type: 'float'` attribute? Like `decimalPlaces: 4` or something of that ilk?

The problem is that when i post a value to this entry, the value on disk is truncated to the `.00` (hundreds) place.  Say I want: `3243.2352362` to be stored just as it is. Currently this is transformed into `3243.24`

If it matters I'm using the sails-mysql adapter.

Comment: Ever get any success with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  types: {
    decimal2: function(number){
      return ((number *100)%1 === 0);
    }
  },
  attributes: {
    myNumber: {
      type: 'float',
      decimal2: true
    }
  }
```

This is for 2 decimal places though. I cant find a way to make it for dynamically changing N as there is afaik no way to pass a parameter to custom validation.
Workaround for this issue would be to check for custom amount of decimal places in `beforeValidation()` function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean dynamic. I just mean arbitrary. This doesn't really fix what I'm dealing with, which is the model chopping off decimal places beyond `0.00`

Comment: You would have to multiply the number by a larger number. It is 100 for 2 decimal places, for 6 places its 10^6 thats 1000000.
The validation rule simply multiplies the number to reduce the amount of decimal places and then does %1 to check if there is any remainder.

Comment: Sorry, see the edit. I'm not looking for a validation rule but rather preventing the truncation of a value I've posted.

Comment: You know, now that I look back I see what you were doing here. I didn't get it before. This is a good workaround. But I am still hoping there is a way to simply store the data with the decimals so I don't have to add this logic every time I extract data too.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend (and I don't think its possible for `float`, maybe) adding a constraint in the model.

I'd suggest that you set:

> migrate: "safe"

in your model and set the appropriate datatype/decimal Places in your tables.

Comment: I considered this. Guess it's yet another issue to be opened. Sorry, I've just hit a lot of walls with sails today.